# displaying index array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a question. I am trying to display the maximum value's index in an array. I was able to obtain the maximum value; however, I don't know to display the index for that maximum value.

For instance, if index [3] had a value of 5 and were the largest element in an array, it would print:

value[3] = 5 is the largest element

How do I do that?

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class ArrayExample 
    {
            public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            //Question 1
            int values[] = new int[5] ;
            System.out.println("Please enter 5 values for this array: ");
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


              System.out.println("Maximum Value = " + getMaxIndex(values) + getMaxValue(values));  
        }

        public static int getMaxValue(int[] values){  
            int maxValue = values[0];  
            for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++){  
                if(values[i] > maxValue){  
                    maxValue = values[i];  
            }  
            }  
        return maxValue;  
    } 
    public static int getHighestMonth(int[] values) {
            int highest = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                if (values[i] > values[highest]) {
                    highest = i;
                }
            }
            return highest;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`:

```
public static SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer> getMaxValue(int[] values){  
    int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int maxIndex = -1;
    for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++){  
        if(values[i] >= maxValue){  
            maxValue = values[i];
            maxIndex = i;
        }  
    }
    return new SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer>( maxIndex, maxValue);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer> maxEntry = getMaxValue( new int[]{1,2,3});

    System.out.println( "value["+ maxEntry.getKey() + "] = " + maxEntry.getValue() + " is the largest element");
    //value[2] = 3 is the largest element

}
```

Comment: Don't overcompicate things... its a simple task

Comment: @firephil there is no way in java to return multiple values without using an object, might as well use an existing class than to create a new one.

Comment: returning the maxIndex is the simplest and best solution no need to complicate things

Answer (score 1):

Hope the below code may help you

```
public static int getMaxIndex(int[] values) {
    int maxValue = values[0];
    int maxIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (values[i] > maxValue) {
            maxValue = values[i];
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return maxIndex;
}
```

Comment: And I would prefer to start with `Integer.MIN_VALUE` in `maxValue` and `-1` in `maxIndex`.

Answer (score 1):

You create a instance variable called position:

```
public class ArrayExample 
    {
    private static int position = 0;
     ...

    }
```

in your getMaxValue you also save the position along with the maxValue:

```
    public static int getMaxValue(int[] values){  
        int maxValue = values[0];  
        for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++){  
            if(values[i] > maxValue){  
                maxValue = values[i]; 
                position = i;
        }  
        }  
    return maxValue;  
}
```

then you print it outside:

```
System.out.println("Maximum Value = " + getMaxIndex(values) + "in position" + position);
```

Or another approach is to, return the position instead of the maxValue:

```
public static int getMaxValue(int[] values){  
            int maxValue = values[0];  
            int position = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++){  
                if(values[i] > maxValue){  
                    maxValue = values[i]; 
                    position = i;
            }  
            }  
        return position;  
    }
```

and outside the you do:

```
int position = getMaxIndex(values);
System.out.println("Maximum Value = " + values[position] + "in position" + position);
```